# How to read the values from the xml using Java?

Tags: java, xml

I'm automating a web application. For that automation writing code in JAVA in Eclipse.

I have the XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>

<logindetails id="1001">
<url>https://XXX</url>
    <username>XX</username>
    <password>XX</password>
</logindetails >

<kpi id="1001">
    <id_r>reports</id_r>
    <id_e>extranet</id_e>
    <id_pr>ext-pr</id_pr>
</kpi>  
<prkpi id="1001">
    <id_1>ext-pr-backlog-age</id_1>
    <id_2>ext-timetoassign-prs</id_2>
    <id_3>ext-timetodeliver-prs</id_3>
    <id_4>ext-timetoresolve-prs</id_4>
    <id_5>ext-new-prs</id_5>


</prkpi>

</project>
```

But My problem in the code is

```
   Log.info("Clicking on Reports link");
        if(existsElement("id_r")==true){
            String id_r = a.readXML("kpi","id_r");
            System.out.println(id_r);
               WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id(id_r));
               System.out.println(id_r);
               actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
               Thread.sleep(6000);
               }
               else{
                   Log.info("element not present");
                   System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");

            }
```

It is not reading the KPI part from the XML and it it is not clicking in the browser application.
If i put these two lines

```
 String id_r = a.readXML("kpi","id_r");
 System.out.println(id_r);
```

Outside the If part it is reading from the XML and printing but My case it should read and it should click in the browser application.

Comment: what happens if you open your xml in any browser. Is it a well formed document

Comment: Please do separate these two issues. *One:* can you read from the XML and everything works as expected? *Two:* can you click on elements etc. when the parameters are given as static strings?

Comment: @vikeng21 it is showing the message at the top of the XML when opening in FF. `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`